# ruby on rails not catching 2 part words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm working within ruby on rails, but I basically know nothing about it. I'm actually not even sure what language I'm having a problem with atm b/c the file that I"m working in has a ".coffee" ending on it.

Here is my code:

```
agentsPerProvince = {
  Ontario: ['James Laird', 'Bryan Freeman', 'Ahjaz Mussa', 'Vince Anton', 'Michael Capobianco'],
  Quebec: ['Philippe Simard', 'Michael Jacyk', 'Philippe Breault'],
  Alberta: ['Matt Leggett', 'Cassia Miller', 'Christie Romeril', 'Ryan Jejina'],
  Saskatchewan: ['Matt Leggett', 'Cassia Miller', 'Christie Romeril'],
  Manitoba: ['James Laird', 'Bryan Freeman', 'Ahjaz Mussa', 'Vince Anton', 'Michael Capobianco'],
  British_Columbia: ['Amrita Singh'],
}
```

the issue is that my web app is not catching the "British Columbia" tag. What is suppose to be happening is that when someone selects "British Columbia" that single agent is suppose to show up in another drop down. It works for all other probinces except British Columbia and I think that's b/c it's two words.

I've tried the following:

```
British_Columbia
British-Columbia
BritishColumbia
britishcolumbia
```

nothing seems to work. Am I doing something wrong? please help!

Comment: thanks Brad. Ya I ended up just doing 'British Columbia' without the underscore and that worked

Comment: BTW, .coffee is CoffeeScript, a language that is transcompiled into Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

What you are working on is a `CoffeeScript` file, basically a ruby-like version of Javascript. You can try it here: http://coffeescript.org/

What you should do is probably make the `British_Columbia` tag like this:

```
'British Columbia': ['Amrita Singh'],
```

instead of

```
British_Columbia: ['Amrita Singh'],
```

or any other combination of characters.

Try this:

```
agentsPerProvince = { 
  Ontario: ['James Laird', 'Bryan Freeman', 'Ahjaz Mussa', 'Vince Anton', 'Michael Capobianco'],
  Quebec: ['Philippe Simard', 'Michael Jacyk', 'Philippe Breault'],
  Alberta: ['Matt Leggett', 'Cassia Miller', 'Christie Romeril', 'Ryan Jejina'],
  Saskatchewan: ['Matt Leggett', 'Cassia Miller', 'Christie Romeril'],
  Manitoba: ['James Laird', 'Bryan Freeman', 'Ahjaz Mussa', 'Vince Anton', 'Michael Capobianco'],
  'British Columbia': ['Amrita Singh'],
}
```

Comment: No reason a valid JS symbol wouldn't work as a key; the problem is likely elsewhere. If you load my example into the CS site and do `alert JSON.stringify agentsPerProvince, null, 2` you can see it's perfectly valid.

Comment: I bet he is trying to search for a `British Columbia` key inside of the `agentsPerProvince` hash given as an input from some other drop down.

Answer (score 0):

All of the options you list except for the one with the dash `-` work just fine. The only requirement is that it be a valid JavaScript symbol.

Unrelated, but more canonically it would be:

```
agentsPerProvince =
  Ontario: ['James Laird', 'Bryan Freeman', 'Ahjaz Mussa', 'Vince Anton', 'Michael Capobianco']
  Quebec: ['Philippe Simard', 'Michael Jacyk', 'Philippe Breault']
  Alberta: ['Matt Leggett', 'Cassia Miller', 'Christie Romeril', 'Ryan Jejina']
  Saskatchewan: ['Matt Leggett', 'Cassia Miller', 'Christie Romeril']
  Manitoba: ['James Laird', 'Bryan Freeman', 'Ahjaz Mussa', 'Vince Anton', 'Michael Capobianco']
  British_Columbia: ['Amrita Singh']
```

Note no surrounding `{}` (redundant) and no trailing commas (optional).

It's more likely your code isn't being reloaded.

Comment: You can actually leave a trailing comma in CoffeeScript hashes as you can in ruby.

Comment: @marzapower Not all browsers deal with trailing commas well (looking at you, old IE).

Comment: CoffeScript has to be compiled to Javascript, and in the resulting Javascript code the comma won't be there. Try it: http://coffeescript.org/#try:a%20%3D%0A%20%20test%3A%201%2C

Comment: @marzapower Oh, okay. Still ugly, though since they're optional to begin with.